# How to remove prev . prev object? Javascript .prev().remove();

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's like

```
<input name="fails[]" type="file" size=40 /><br />
<textarea name="apraksts[]">About</textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="remove(this);return false".....>remove</a>
```

And the javascript:

```
function remove(obj){
 $(obj).prev('textarea').remove();
 $(obj).prev('input').remove();
 $(obj).remove();
 }
```

Why it doesnt remove INPUT(why it doesnt remove two objects)?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for prev says it:

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

After you remove the `<textarea>`, that element is a `<br>`. Since it doesn't match `input`, the resulting jQuery object contains no elements. You then remove those 0 objects.

---

I suspect a better approach to the problem would be to wrap all the elements in a `<div>` (or a container with more suitable semantics for the context) and remove *that* (instead of removing each element in turn).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use prevAll.  That will select all previous sibling elements which are then filtered by your selector:

$(obj).prevAll('input').remove();